# Using the updated item in a trigger

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, oracle12c

I am trying to create an SQL trigger for when the quantity on hand (qoh) of an item in the Oracle 12c SQL database falls below 5. I want to select the description of that item from another table, and have come up with the following query, but I am getting an error when I try to run it:

```
/*Creates a trigger to notify someone when an item is out of stock*/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ItemOutOfStock
AFTER UPDATE OF INV_QOH ON inventory
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.INV_QOH < 5)
BEGIN
SELECT I.ITEM_DESC
FROM ITEMS I
WHERE I.ITEM_ID = new.ITEM_ID;
END;
/
```

From what I have been able to figure out I should be able to call `new.item_id` and it works, but that isn't the case. When I update the inventory table and set an item's quantity to less than 5 with just a `dbms_output.put_line` command it puts the text to the output, so I know the problem is somewhere in the select statement.

Comment: What do you want to do with the result?  An Oracle trigger cannot just have a `select`, the data has to go somewhere.

Comment: Oh. Hmm. Well I need to send an email with the procedure, so I need to get the item description and pass that to a stored send_email procedure. So I was just using the select statement to get the ball rolling then I was going to store the item description in a varchar2 variable.

Comment: It's always helpful to include the actual error that you're getting rather than just saying that you're "getting an error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SELECT` statement has to do something with the data.  Potentially, you could store the data in a local variable declared in your trigger.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ItemOutOfStock
  AFTER UPDATE OF INV_QOH ON inventory
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.INV_QOH < 5)
DECLARE
  l_item_desc item.item_desc%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT I.ITEM_DESC
    INTO l_item_desc
    FROM ITEMS I
   WHERE I.ITEM_ID = :new.ITEM_ID;

  <<do something with l_item_desc>>
END;
/
```

Note that the `:new` pseudo-record needs to be prefaced with a colon.

Be aware as well that sending an email from a trigger is generally a bad idea since sending an email is non-transactional.  A trigger can be fired but the transaction can be rolled back so the email can get sent even though the update was never committed.  A trigger can also be executed multiple times for a single change (with a rollback in between) because of write consistency.  To do it correctly, you'd really want the trigger to do something like write to a table that a separate processes polls periodically in order to send emails or to submit a job (using `dbms_job`) that sends an email if and only if the underlying transaction commits.